# a.frame_Using j.rumble code in an aframe scene?

Tags: jquery, html, aframe

Im building in an a-scene and so far have only used html. I found the j.rumble code from j.query and I've put the source code into my document head but I'm having trouble coding the rumble event on my entities in my a-scene. I'm new to coding so I'm still figuring out how everything meshes together. I'm trying to get the rumble effect to happen on an event, when the mouse hovers over a cube I want the cube to rumble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

j.rumble only works on 2D web elements. A-Frame runs in WebGL.